# Yii2 list items inside a categories

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

My controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Documents::find();
    $docs = $query->orderBy('cate_id ASC')->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        'docs' => $docs,
    ]);
}
```

My view

```
<?php foreach ($docs as $doc) {  
$cate = app\models\Categories::find()->where(['id'=>$doc->cate_id])->one();?>
    <h4><?=$cate->title?></h4>
    <p><?= Html::a($doc->title, ['documents/view', 'id'=>$doc->id]) ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

**With this my view look like**

*Category 1*

- Menu Item Title 1

*Category 1*

- Menu Item Title 2

*Category 2*

- Menu Item Title 3

**I want it to display**

*Categories 1*

- Menu Item Title 1
- Menu Item Title 2

*Categories 2*

- Menu Item Title 3

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your task, use Yii `ArrayHelper` to solve this problem very easily.

Check this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html

You can group the records according to a specific key/column by using `ArrayHelper::index` method.

In your case, you have to group the records with 'cate_id' (which refers your category id).

```
   //dont forget to import ArrayHelper before using it. 
   //use \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper.
   $catList = ArrayHelper::index($docs, null, 'cate_id');
```

Above code will produce grouped array. example....

```
   [
        1 =>[
              ['Menu Item Title 1','other column data','....'],
              ['Menu Item Title 2','other column data','....']
        ],
        2 =>[
              ['Menu Item Title 3','other column data','....'],
              ['Menu Item Title 4','other column data','....']
        ]

   ]
```

Now you iterate through this array/array object.

```
     <?php
     foreach($catList as $cate_id => $catItems)
     {
        $cate = app\models\Categories::find()->where(['id'=>$cate_id])->one();
        echo '<h4>'.$cate->title.'</h4>';
        foreach($catItems as $catItem)
        {

           echo '<p>'.Html::a($catItem['title'], ['documents/view', 'id'=>$catItem['id']]).'</p>';
        }

     }
     ?>
```

After getting some grip on Yii code, try to code in Yii way. That is, in this case, do not write queries in `View`.

You can use model `relation` to get the name of the category.

Comment: I dont really understand the "foreach($catList as $cate_id => $catItems)" part.
Can you explain it? Thank you

Comment: print $catList to understand it. `print_r($catList)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your view :

```
<?php 
foreach ($docs as $doc) {  
  $cate = app\models\Categories::find()->where(['id'=>$doc->cate_id])->all();?> // query for all records
  ?>
  <h4><?=$doc->title?></h4>
  <?php
  foreach ($cate as $cat {  
  ?>
  <p><?= Html::a($cat->title, ['documents/view', 'id'=>$cat->id]) ?></p>
  <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Change according your need.